# Pandas: function that uses multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe df1:

```
date, country, category, score, value
2017-01-01, US, 123, 555, 232.02
2017-01-01, US, 223, 10, 22.02
```

I have a lookup dataframe df2:

```
category, factor_score_0_100, factor_score_101_500, factor_score_501_1000
123, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
223, 5.4, 4.3, 3.2
```

Based on the `category` and `score` of a row in `df1`, I need to get the `factor_score` from df2. If the score in `df1` for a particular category is between 0 and 100, I need to return `factor_score_0_100` for that category and so on.

So far I've been able to convert `df2` into a dictionary of the form

```
category: [factor_score_0_100, factor_score_101_500, factor_score_501_1000]
```

And I was attempting to write a function and then `apply` it via a lambda, but I'm not sure how to use 2 columns as an input.

How can I proceed here?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

A little bit hack to get that using `IntervalIndex` + `lookup`

```
df2=df2.set_index('category')
df2.columns=df2.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)
idx=pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2.columns.get_level_values(2).astype(int),df2.columns.get_level_values(3).astype(int),closed='both')
df2.columns=idx

df2.lookup(df1[' category'],df1[' score'])
Out[171]: array([4. , 5.4])
```

After assign it back

```
df1['NEW']=df2.lookup(df1[' category'],df1[' score'])
df1
Out[173]: 
         date  country   category   score   value  NEW
0  2017-01-01       US        123     555  232.02  4.0
1  2017-01-01       US        223      10   22.02  5.4
```